# Is it possible to move an Part using a macro in CATIA?

Tags: python, vba, catia

I have a CATProduct Assembly, and I want to rotate one of the parts around an axis (specifically the axis of another part, but using the y-axis also works). Using a mouse, I'd open the "Manipulation Tool", select my axis, check the "With respect to constraints", and move my object around the axis. However I want to automate it, so I'm wondering if there's some way I could do so. When I try to record a macro nothing shows up in the result.

So far all I have figured out is
    CATIA.StartCommand("Manipulate")
    ' and
    CATIA.StartCommand("Update")

Which ends up showing this:
[image: what shows up is this]

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible.

The Position and Move Properties of the Product object can be used to manipulate position of parts in an assembly.

Comment: Can you please add an example?